# Why does Metro (AG) not allow everyone to shop there?

Tags: markets

Why does the Metro wholesale allow to shop only for business persons and not to everyone? Do they have some limitations from anyone and why? They will make more money if everyone could shop there.

Comment: "*They will make more money if everyone could shop there.*" This statement is not trivially true. The average personal shopper buys much less than the average business customer, processing payment is relatively slow, and thus the non-bulk shoppers might increase queues or force Metro to hire more cashiers/install more terminals, which might not be worth it.

Comment: I would suspect that the reasons aren't economical but legal: By (officially) not targeting consumers but only businesses, they might be exempt from various consumer protection laws.

Comment: If everyone can shop there then Metro would not have membership fee revenue. You have to subtract that revenue before concluding that Metro would make more money if it welcomed everybody.

Comment: You dont need to pay for membership.

Comment: https://www.it-recht-kanzlei.de/b2b-verkauf-gewerbetreibende-zul%C3%A4ssige-einschr%C3%A4nkung-voraussetzungen.html is very informative. It's in German but Google translate on Chrome or android worked well enough to understand it. There are primarily legal reasons and the way metro operates right now is illegal for retail. They mention opening hours, price declarations, etc. Seems there have been several law suits by retail associations against metro because of alleged violations of retail consumer rights while allowing clients with retail shopping behaviours into stores

Answer (score 0):

There are several reasons for this.

The taxes on products are shown because they are deductible in the tax return.

In addition, the volumes are much larger. For example, 20 packs of cereal or 25 kg of potatoes. Customers do not buy such volumes.

If Metro would also sell to end customers, they would have to adjust to them and offer smaller sizes, etc.

Wholesaling is a different business than retail.

Comment: what if an individual wants to buy 25kg of potatoes?

Comment: Given these reasons, wouldn't end consumers simply "self select" and not go to Metro? What is the point of outright allowing only business consumers?

Comment: Not sure where you are from, but where I live, Metro and other wholesale chains have products which clearly also target private consumers. My mom had a Metro card through her employer and frequently used it to shop there for regular household consumption. The company she worked for didn't actually bought anything there. They just handed out those cards as an unofficial employee benefit.

Comment: Yeah, last week I was in Metro for the first time, we got the card and buyed items for ourself, like other people who were there, no big packages, just normal shopping. So I don't think it wouldnt be beneficial. There should be some legal limitation from the producers of the products, but what kind of?